# Google Groups Membership

Tags: google-groups

I have a problem with new google groups. I require new members to answer a question to join my group. How can I ask a membership question in new google groups?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to set the Google Group permissions to "invite only" then write a website script that asks the user the question and if they answer correctly, adds them to the group via the Google Apps Provisioning API:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#adding_a_member_to_a_group